# How can I modify cordova-aurelia-skeleton to use skeleton-es2016-webpack

Tags: node.js, cordova, webpack, aurelia

I am diving into Cordova development, and want to build the basic "Hello World" app using Aurelias skeleton-es2016-webpack. This is my first Cordova project and I am new to Aurelia and gulp.

Background: PHP/MySQL/JQuery/some Python/Ubuntu. Deleloping on OSX

Got cordova-aurelia-skeleton ( https://github.com/fragsalat/cordova-aurelia-skeleton ) up and running fine. However, it uses jspm as a package manager and "transpiles" the EMCAScript6 to EMCAScript5. I would prefer the skeleton-es2016-webpack that only uses npm and Webpack.

What would be involved in using skeleton-es2016-webpack instead?

Comment: There is an Aurelia Cordova with Webpack Skeleton at https://github.com/arjendeblok/aurelia-cordova-skeleton. Please read the 2 closed issues to make it work on Android.